Is there an automorphism of $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ with $(x,0)\mapsto(x,x)$?
The question:
Does there exist a diffeomorphism $\alpha:\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ such that for some $x_0\in\mathbb{S}^2$ and every $x\in\mathbb{S}^2$ we have $\alpha(x,x_0)=(x,x)$?
Failed ideas:
I understood that if in place of $\mathbb{S}^2$ we had any Lie group, then this would exist: $(x,y)\mapsto(x,x+y)$, but $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not the manifold of a Lie group so I can't apply it in this case. That's where this question comes from. Another idea that I can't even check is checking whether or not $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\mathbb{S}^2\times\{x_0\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{S}^2\}$. For now I know these spaces are both homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^2$. Third idea, can the hairy-ball theorem somehow be applied?
In other words:
Using $\Delta:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2:x\mapsto(x,x)$, can we complete the sequence
$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2\xrightarrow{\;\Delta\;}\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\xrightarrow{\;?\;}\;?\rightarrow0$$
so it becomes exact and splits?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No such diffeomorphism exists, for the following reasons.
In general, given a compact, connected, oriented manifold and submanifold $M \subset N$ of codimension $k$, the normal bundle $\nu^M_N = T_M N \bigm/ T M$ is a $k$-dimensional vector bundle over $M$, and it is a diffeomorphism invariant of the pair $(M,N)$. If the dimension of $N$ equals $2k$, and so the dimension of $M$ and the dimension of the fibers of $\nu$ are both equal to $k$, then $\nu$ has an Euler number, which is an integer invariant of $\nu$, and that number is a diffeomorphism invariant of $(M,N)$.
Now let's consider the case $M=S^2 \times S^2$. For $N=S^2 \times \{x\}$, the normal bundle is isomorphic to the product $S^2 \times \mathbb R^2$, and its Euler number is $0$. But for $N=\Delta$, the normal bundle is isomorphic to the tangent bundle $TS^2$, and its Euler number equals the Euler characteristic of $S^2$ which equals $2$. Welp, $0 \ne 2$ so no diffeomorphism of $S^2 \times S^2$ exists taking $S^2 \times \{x\}$ to $\Delta$.
From a more geometric standpoint, one can unwind all of this to get the following statements. First, there exists a section of the normal bundle of $S^2 \times \{0\}$ that is nonzero at every point. However, every section of the normal bundle of $\Delta$ has a zero; this is indeed, as you intuited, a version of the Hairy ball theorem. But it can be unwound one step further: on $S^2 \times S^2$ there exist a vector field which is nowhere tangent to $S^2 \times \{0\}$; but for any vector field on $S^2 \times S^2$, there is at least one point of $\Delta$ such that at that point the vector field is tangent to $\Delta$.

Actually, I have just started learning the theory behind Euler numbers so this answer is very useful to me at this moment!

There is no such automorphism, considering its action on the cohomology algebra.
The cohomology of $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$, by Künneth, is an algebra with two degree-2 generators, $a$ and $b$ where $a^2 = 0, b^2 = 0$ and $ab = c$, a generator of $H^4$.
Suppose we have an automorphism of $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2$ that maps the first sphere onto the diagonal. By poincaré duality, this implies it would map (for example) $a$ to $(a + b)$ and $b$ to something else. Does such an automorphism exist ?
No because $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b² + 2ab = 2c \neq 0$ (in degree 2, the cup product is commutative). Thus, we cannot map $a$ to $a + b$.
Interestingly, this explains why it is possible for $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$: in this case, $(a + b)^2 = a² + b^2 + ab - ab = 0$, so there is no obstruction (the cup product is anti-commutative in degree 1).

I really don't understand this theory, so I have to just ask you: can these arguments answer the question when $\mathbb{S}^5$ is used instead of $\mathbb{S}^2$?

@cnikbesku I believe the argument only works for spheres of even dimension.

Ok, that's exactly why I asked. It seems all three solutions work only for spheres of even dimension.

It doesn't exist.
First calim: the manifold $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{S}^2\}$ strongly deformation-retracts to $\{(x,-x):x\in\mathbb{S}^2\}$.
Let $\pi_1,\pi_2:\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ be the functions of the first and second coordinates.
Let's define $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ so that $\alpha(x,y)=(\alpha_1(x,y),\alpha_2(x,y))$, i.e. $\alpha_i=\pi_i\circ\alpha$.
For every $y\in\mathbb{S}^2$, let $e_y$ be the embedding $\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2:x\mapsto(x,y)$.
Second claim: all $e_y$'s are homotopic to each other.
Take some $y\neq x_0$. Consider $\alpha\circ e_{x_0}$. Second claim implies $\alpha\circ e_{x_0}$ is homotopic to $\alpha\circ e_y$. The images of $e_{x_0}$ and $e_y$ are disjoint, and since $\alpha$ is a bijection, the image of $\alpha\circ e_y$ is disjoint from $\alpha\circ e_{x_0}$, i.e. it is inside of $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{S}^2\}$. First claim now implies that $\alpha\circ e_y:x\mapsto(\alpha_1(x,y),\alpha_2(x,y))$ is homotopic to $x\mapsto(\alpha_1(x,y),-\alpha_1(x,y))=(\alpha_1\circ e_y,-\alpha_1\circ e_y)$. Second claim implies that $(\alpha_1\circ e_y,-\alpha_1\circ e_y)$ is homotopic to $(\alpha_1\circ e_{x_0},-\alpha_1\circ e_{x_0})=(\text{id},-\text{id})$. Summarized, $\alpha\circ e_{x_0}=(\text{id},\text{id})$ is homotopic to $(\text{id},-\text{id})$. After composing with $\pi_2$ we get that $\text{id}$ and $-\text{id}$ are homotopic which they aren't since their degrees are $1$ and $-1$ (different).
